# If I spin an electromagnet do I create a stationary electromagnetic wave?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

Since its the same fundamental forces I would imagine it would. Or, is it radiating the waves and it would only look like a stationary "wave"?

Comment: What do you mean by a stationary wave?

Comment: Why do you think this would create a wave, whether travelling or stationary?  Same fundamental forces as what?  Please can you explain your thinking.  Also, what have you tried to find an answer eg on the internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The far-field strength, $B$, of a dipole magnetic field has an angular dependence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dipole#Field_of_a_static_magnetic_dipole) and hence so does the energy density (proportional to $B^2$). If the field simply rotated with the magnet then regions of high/low energy density would also rotate. Suppose the magnet is rotating once per second. Then at distances >>1 light-second we would have energy moving around faster than the speed of light. This shows that the simple idea of a rotating $B$ field is not valid.

A correct treatment shows that EM radiation is emitted. If you supplied power to keep the magnet rotating, the fields would rotate and (eventually) be periodic at any point in space, but this is not a  "stationary wave" by definition.

Answer (score -2):

> If I spin an electromagnet do I create a stationary electromagnetic wave?

No. See [this webpage](http://education.jlab.org/qa/createenergy_02.html). You get a spinning magnetic field.

> Since its the same fundamental forces I would imagine it would. Or, is it radiating the waves and it would only look like a stationary "wave"?

This is an interesting subject, but I think you're coming at it from the wrong end. Have a look at [pair production](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_production). You start with an electromagnetic wave, and you end up with electron spin and a stationary  electromagnetic field. IMHO the interesting question is [how](http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath619/kmath619.htm) do you make that standing electromagnetic field out of an electromagnetic wave.

[image]

Note that in [atomic orbitals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbital#Electron_properties), electrons *"exist as standing waves"*. Standing wave, standing field.